# Как поднять Maven проект на Tomcate

Tags: веб-программирование, jsp, maven, tomcat

Привет!
Есть скачанный Maven проект, рабочий (веб приложение). Также есть логин и пароль к этому приложению.

Надо поднять это приложение на Tomcat.

Импортировал этот проект в Eclipse - очень много файлов помеченных красным, то есть ошибки. Но ошибки такие, что отсутствуют getter и  setter методы. Но так как используется lombok библиотека то проект компилируется без проблем. Но этот же проект не билдится, то есть при выполнении команды **mvn package** выдается ошибка при начале тестов.

Пытаюсь отдельно запускать на сервере Tomcat файл index.jsp тоже не работает.

Как правильно развертывать этот Maven web проект на Tomcat?

Логи при билде с тестами:

```
d:\SoftwareDevelopment\Java\workspaceEE\MavenProject>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Штатное расписание 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ personal ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ personal -
--
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 189 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ personal ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pe
rsonal ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory d:\SoftwareDevelopment\Java\workspace
EE\MavenProject\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ persona
l ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ personal ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: d:\SoftwareDevelopment\Java\workspaceEE\MavenP
roject\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configur
ator@29444d75
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.In
vocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetE
xception: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(
ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke
(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(Provi
derFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(Fork
edBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:
75)
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException:
Cannot instantiate class ru.dcvit.personal.service.impl.optimal.OptimalServiceDa
yModuleImplNGTest
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.j
ava:38)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)

        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:115)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:200)
        at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:1
20)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRu
nner.java:536)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.ja
va:77)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMult
i(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(Tes
tNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider
.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.j
ava:29)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        The method setWorkScheduleService(WorkScheduleServiceImpl) is undefined
for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl
        The method getExternal() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getExternal() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setCalcId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalDayParameter
s
        The method setOrgId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalDayParameters

        The method setStoreId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalDayParamete
rs
        The method setWorkAreaId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalDayParam
eters
        The method getMhrs() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method setNextDayList(ArrayList<Mhr>) is undefined for the type Opti
malDayParameters
        The method getResourceCosts() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvid
er
        The method getResources() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method getResources() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method getWorkSchedules() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvid
er
        The method getRankCoefs() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method setOperationId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalDayPara
meters
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDailyPlan
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDailyPlan
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDailyPlan
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDailyPlan
        The method getPlans() is undefined for the type OptimalDailyPlan
        The method getMhrs() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setNextDayA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalService
DayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setCalcId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayMo
duleImpl.CalcData
        The method getMhrs() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setCostOfHour(BigDecimal) is undefined for the type WorkResou
rceType
        The method setRankId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setCostOfHour(BigDecimal) is undefined for the type WorkResou
rceType
        The method setRankId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setCostOfHour(BigDecimal) is undefined for the type WorkResou
rceType
        The method setRankId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method getCostOfHour() is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setModules(List<List<OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModu
le>>) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setExtraModules(List<OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModu
le>) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setOrgId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayMod
uleImpl.CalcData
        The method setShortestModule(OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModule)
 is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setStoreId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayM
oduleImpl.CalcData
        The method setFreqs(HashMap<WorkResourceType,Integer>) is undefined for
the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setFreqModules(ArrayList<OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.Resource
Module>) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setRankCoef(HashMap<Long,BigDecimal>) is undefined for the ty
pe OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method getRankCoef() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setOperationId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalService
DayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method getDailyPlan() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayMod
uleImpl.CalcMatrixResult
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getResourceId() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getHoursQ() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method getPlanTime() is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setNextDayA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalService
DayModuleImpl.CalcData
        The method setCalcId(long) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayMo
duleImpl.CalcData
        The method getMhrs() is undefined for the type OptimalDayProvider
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setCostOfHour(BigDecimal) is undefined for the type WorkResou
rceType
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setResourceId(long) is undefined for the type HRPlan
        The method setModule(OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModule) is unde
fined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.SolutionData
        The method setPreferredTimeStart(int) is undefined for the type OptimalS
erviceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModule
        The method setModule(OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.ResourceModule) is unde
fined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImpl.SolutionData
        The method getMin() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImp
l.MhrInterval
        The method getMin() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImp
l.MhrInterval
        The method getMin() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImp
l.MhrInterval
        The method getMin() is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModuleImp
l.MhrInterval
        The method setId(long) is undefined for the type WorkResourceType
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData
        The method setA(int[][]) is undefined for the type OptimalServiceDayModu
leImpl.CalcData

        at ru.dcvit.personal.service.impl.optimal.OptimalServiceDayModuleImplNGT
est.<init>(OptimalServiceDayModuleImplNGTest.java:43)
        ... 34 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.517 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-30T16:19:59+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project personal: Execution default-test of goal org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM te
rminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [H
elp 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutio
nException
```

Comment: можно попробовать запустить сборку без тестов `mvn package -DskipTests` или добавить в вопрос логи мавена с ошибками.

Comment: выполнил эту команду - проект собрался в .war файл.
Как теперь его запустить на Tomcat сервере?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - задеплоить через менеджер: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely

Comment: что касается логов при билде с тестами, то я добавил их в вопрос сверху